# Unable to start PCF Dev (cf dev start) on Ubuntu because of missing KVM

Tags: pcfdev

Trying to start PCF Dev on an Ubuntu 19.10; fails with the bellow output:

```sh
$ cf dev start
Downloading Resources...
Progress: |====================>| 100.0%
Setting State...
Error: argument "virbr0" is wrong: Device does not exist

Cannot find device "virbr0"
Creating the VM...
Starting the VM...
Fetching VM Address...
FAILED
cf dev start: exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out [KVM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM) is required to be installed:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-clients bridge-utils
```

Source: [Installation of KVM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation#Installation_of_KVM)